# Where can I purchase a block of aluminium?

Tags: metal, aluminum, metal-cutting

I'm need a 5" x 5" x 1" block of aluminium.  Is this something I can buy online and are there different types of aluminum to consider? Will I have to buy a bigger piece and cut the aluminum down to my specific size?

I need a solid base that I can tap with hole to mount into a DIY slider dolly.

Comment: I'd go scrounge around a junkyard if you have one near where you live. That's where I got all of my scrap metal for college design projects. If you get a big enough hunk of aluminum, it will often have the exact type stamped on it. Of course, you'll need access to metal cutting tools like a band saw or mill as well.

Comment: There are videos online about how to build your own very simple forge that can melt aluminum cans to make your own aluminum casts.  A 5" x 5" x 1" block is probably a simple shape to cast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several online metal suppliers that will also make custom cuts.  [Online Metals](http://www.onlinemetals.com) is one that I have used.  There is a minimum length that you must order (usually 1 ft) and a charge per cut.  Depending on where you live you might also find a local metal supplier that can do the same for you.

Wherever you order, I'd suggest you get two 5" pieces cut from 1ft of 1" x 5" bar and then you'd have a spare.  I would definitely try to have someone else do the cutting for a piece that size.  Rectangular tubing might also be something to consider.

Here is a reference on the same supplier for the [aluminum alloys](http://www.onlinemetals.com/aluminumguide.) they stock.  Be sure to check the prices as they'll vary, but I believe 6061 is one of the more widely used alloys.

Comment: I've had good experiences with Speedy Metals: http://www.speedymetals.com/pc-2511-8378-5-sq-6061-t6511-aluminum-extruded.aspx They'll sell you a 5X5X1" block of 6061 aluminum for under $14.00 plus shipping

Answer (score 0):

It's a little wierd to use such a thick block of metal for anything (except making a die or something), so you may want to rethink your design, whatever it is.

I would definitely check eBay first, because it will be a LOT cheaper than going to a metal shop. BTW the kind of dealer you want is called "non ferrous".

Some places will sell off cuts and scrap by the pound and once again that will be a lot cheaper than buying it custom. You do not say where your location is in your profile, so not sure what dealers are in your area.

As Jay says, get a pro to cut it, because setting up to cut metal, while not terribly difficult, sounds like it is beyond your skill level right now.

As for the type of aluminum, I wouldn't worry about it for something like this.

Comment: Even 2" round aluminum will cause you to work up a sweat if you go after it with a hacksaw. Plus, the cut line will wander on you. A powered miter saw with carbide blade will cut at least 4X4" aluminum pretty cleanly, but you'll  be buying new blades on a regular basis if you cut metal very often.